# Mongoid min aggregation returning incorrect value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a collection called data. Each document looks something like this:

```
x: {"value"=>1358747699.6922424}, y: {"value"=>17.9}
```

Also, I have indexes on x.value and y.value. Using the built in mongoid aggregation .min, I wanted to get the minimum y value. I tried doing this:

```
data.min(:'y.value')
```

and it returns 16.2, which I know is not correct, it should be 14.4, which I can prove by:

```
data.map{|d| d['y']d['value']}.sort.first
```

returns 14.4

Or:

```
data.order_by([:'y.value', :asc]).limit(1).first['y']['value']
```

Also returns 14.4

So I can't figure out why .min does not seem to be working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**

In your case, just ignore the `min` function provided by Mongoid. Use the one you came up with instead:

```
data.order_by([:'y.value', :asc]).limit(1).first['y']['value']
```

**Explanation**

I did some digging into how the Mongoid aggregations are actually implemented. Turns out they use a `map_reduce` that runs the entire collection. [[1]](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/contextual/aggregable/mongo.rb)

The query that you wrote should be much more efficient because it can use that index you built on `y.value`. That means 1 index lookup versus the entire collection (not to mention it actually works...).

Check the MongoDB profiler to ensure your indexes are actually being used. [[2]](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/)

**The Question you Actually Asked**

As far as exactly why `min` fails, I am at a loss. Without seeing your data, I can't see any reason why the underlying `map_reduce` would fail. Maybe it has to do with the embedded field or maybe `this.y.value` is not defined for some objects.

Here's an opportunity to give back to open source. Try posting to the [Mongoid issues board](https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues). Be sure to crosslink if you do. I'd like to see the resolution for this.